# Changing scroll direction issues word 13

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

I am using Microsoft Word '13 on a laptop (meaning a trackpad), and I do work wherein I need to scroll up and down frequently.  When I do this and I change direction (switch from scrolling up to down, and vice versa), the document continues scrolling in the original direction for some period of time. (this period is actually determined via distance: scrolling one direction, stopping, and then scrolling the other direction produces the same result)  This "scrolling up the document when I am telling the document to move down" happens often enough that it becomes irksome.  Is there a setting somewhere that I have missed?  Is there some other fix?

To be clear I am **Not** looking to invert the direction of document scroll in relation to the direction my fingers move on the trackpad.  That inversion and the disabling of fluid scrolling are the only support issues I've found thus far.  I am running Win7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using keyboard arrow keys to scroll? or a scrollpad area on the treackpad? or clicking a screen object such as the scroll bar? or something else? If its the arrow keys, then your keyboard auto-repeat function is much faster than the screen can update. Holding the key down is actually causing many repeats, which are being buffered waiting for the screen movement to catch up before it grabs the next one out of the queue.  Fast scrolling of a large word document the keypresses may get 100's or 1000's ahead, which is why the document keeps moving when you let up on the key.

Comment: My trackpad has a "two-finger scroll" option, which does work across the entirety of the trackpad. No arrow keys used.  It is possible I get ahead of the screens updating - some of these files are 200+ pages - but I think I can rule this out based on the fact that I can scroll up, stop for several seconds, and then scroll down.  This stopping makes no difference in the scrolling behavior.  It should be noted that this act of scrolling in several directions is done in one motion.  Temporarily removing my hand from the trackpad does fix it, it's just annoying as heck.

Comment: Probably not what I thought was happening then...

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you are describing "inertial scroll" meaning scroll that continues after you stop moving and/or lift off your fingers.

There are typically two ways that drivers allow you to control inertial scroll (if at all).  One is, don't start it--meaning move slowly and bring your fingers to a stop before lifting them.  The second is to tap while the scrolling is going on--probably one or two fingers, it doesn't matter.

Good luck, I hope your driver is a good one and supports both.